# Error message in Java job class constructor. Help please

Tags: java, constructor, accessor

I'm getting the following error message from my code,

cannot find symbol - variable jobName

We have to create a class called Job with two simple fields Job name and job length.

I don't understand why I'm getting this error message. Code is below. Thanks for help in advance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Job
  {
 // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
 private String name;
 private int duration;
 private boolean isComplete;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Job
 */
public Job(String name, int duration)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    jobName = name;
    jobDuration = duration;


}
/**
 * Accessor method for job name. 
 * 
 * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
 * @return     value of job. 
 */
public String getName() {
    {
        // put your code here
        return jobName;
    }
}

/**
 * Accessor method for job duration.
 * 
 * @param y a sample parameter for a method
 * @return value of job duration.
 * 
 */

public int getDuration() {
    {
        return jobDuration;
    }

}

/**
 * Run method which prints. 
 * 
 * @param y a sample parameter for a method. 
 * @return 
 */

public void run(String name, int duration) {
    if (isComplete) 
    {
        System.out.print("JOB COMPLETE" + jobName);            
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: Please accept one of the answers as an answer to your question and upvote if it helped you. It is the least you can do when somebody invests time in helping you out. You have asked six questions and received answers to them all, but never  accepted one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `jobName` and `jobDuration`, you need to say `this.name` and `this.duration`, since that's what those fields are named.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. Compiled without errors now. Sorry that I'm such a noob at this!

Comment: now it's your turn to actually accept the answer.  if you don't start accepting answers people will stop giving you solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

You named your private data member "name", but you keep referring to it as "jobName".

Answer (score 0):

You constructor is using a new variables named `jobName` and `jobDuration`,  which is not defined. Correct it as below:

```
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Job
     */
    public Job(String name, int duration){
        // initialise instance variables
        name = name;
        duration = duration;
    }
```

Also it is better practice to use different names for arguments and member variables or use `this` before members variables e.g.

```
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Job
     */
    public Job(String aName, int aDuration) {
        // initialise instance variables
        name = aName;
        duration = aDuration;
    }
```

or

```
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Job
     */
    public Job(String name, int duration)   {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
private String name;
private int duration;
```

to this:

```
private String jobName;
private int jobDuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you don't have `jobName` variable in your class I think you have named it as `name`

Answer (score 0):

You have given,

```
private String name;
private int duration;
```

and you are using `jobName, jobDuration` which are not defined. Please either declare these or use,

```
this.name = name;
this.duration = duration;
```